# Static SQL query replace to dynamic column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/752e34/3

This query use SELECT in SELECT queries.

"`SELECT a.*`

> `,(SELECT s.value FROM tbl_scd AS s WHERE s.tag_id = 1 AND s.main_id = a.id ORDER BY s.date_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS title`
>
> `,(SELECT s.value FROM tbl_scd AS s WHERE s.tag_id = 2 AND s.main_id = a.id ORDER BY s.date_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS alt`

`FROM tbl_main AS a`
`WHERE 1;`"

Now I'm looking for a solution to add a new row into tbl_tag without change the above query (that the SELECT in SELECT part will be dynamic) to get a reference to `tbl_tag`

To get this:

```
+----+---------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| id |     date      |    title  |     alt   |   new_column |
+----+---------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |    2018-10-10 |   test1-1 |   test1-3 |   NULL       |
|  2 |    2018-10-11 |   test2-1 |   test2-1 |   NULL       |
+----+---------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

It would be great to get an idea or help.
Thanks

Comment: Request you to please follow the StackOverflow community guidelines for asking questions. You can find the details here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do you mean "add a new column"?  you can, of course, add as many *rows* as you want to, without needing to worry about changing this nor any query; that's what using SQL is all about

Comment: ... also, I don't see any reference to `tbl_tag` at all in the SQL you provided; only changes to tables involved in a query affect that query

Comment: Thx for your help. Yes, you've right. I need a reference to tbl_tag that my query with inner SELECTs may me not necessary.

Comment: what you are asking for is impossible:  you cannot "get a reference to `tbl_tag`" and also do it "without change the above query"

Comment: I thought to another way and start my query with tbl_tag as SELECT and JOIN to tbl_main and tbl_scd but than I don't find a solution to implement the `date_time` (last date) what do you think about?

Answer (score 1):

Your last comment on your question about using `JOIN` makes it clearer to me (I think) what you are after.  `JOIN`s will definitely help you a lot here, in place of the rather cumbersome query you are currently using.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  tbl_main.date,
  tblA.value AS title,
  tblB.value AS alt
FROM
  tbl_main
  INNER JOIN (SELECT main_id, tag_id, value
                FROM tbl_scd
               INNER JOIN tbl_tag ON (tbl_scd.tag_id = tbl_tag.id)
               WHERE tbl_tag.name = 'title') tblA
  ON (tbl_main.id = tblA.main_id)
  INNER JOIN (SELECT main_id, tag_id, value
                FROM tbl_scd
               INNER JOIN tbl_tag ON (tbl_scd.tag_id = tbl_tag.id)
               WHERE tbl_tag.name = 'alt') tblB
   ON (tbl_main.id = tblB.main_id);
```

I think this will get you much closer to a general solution to what it looks like you are trying to achieve, or at least point you in a good direction with using `JOIN`s.

I also think you might benefit from re-thinking your database design, because this kind of pivoting rows from one table into columns in a query output can be an indicator that the data might be better off structured differently.

In any case, I hope this helps.

Comment: that's a good way and I understood. this solution is much faster than my trys. one more question to you. my trys show the newed result of every tag, now we got all. Second, any idea to relinquish explicit declear 'title' and 'alt' in `JOIN`s to get all "tag"s (if one add in tbl_tag)

Comment: @Korty : for showing just the rows you want, you can use regular `WHERE` clauses or `GROUP BY`, etc.;  for making this dynamic to whatever rows happen to be in `tbl_tag`, I don't know of any straight SQL method;  the general type of situation you are facing is a **pivot** situation;  MySQL doesn't have a `PIVOT` function, so to make it truly dynamic I do believe you need to wrap it in programmatic logic, either a SQL procedure, or code to generate the query SQL and then execute the generated query;  Google'ing for `mysql pivot rows to columns` might also give you additional guidance;  HTH!